# opencv project program wont halt

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to begin an opencv project. I have installed all of the dependancies etc.

I am running the following to compile the program
`g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) -std=c++11  main.cpp -o yourFileProgram`

inside of `main.cpp`:

```
 #include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
 #include <iostream>

 cv::RNG rng(12345);

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
 }
```

The code compiles, however when I run `./yourFileProgram` the exec never terminates.

Comment: Mmmm... try removing the RNG stuff and see if that changes anything. Then try removing the OpenCV `#includes` and see if anything changes. Btw, I think there's just a single `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` now.

Comment: Even if i remove everything except for main it still never terminates

Comment: What if you don't link with OpenCV, i.e. remove `--libs` from your compilation command?

Comment: then I get a bunch of undefined symbols Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Comment: The files are not found (ie the headers i have included for opencv)